# How to open an xhtml page in a dialog box in jsf

Tags: jsf, dialog

When I hit the edit button I need a dialog to show corresponding xhtml page. I mean when I press edit, editStudent.xhtml should appear in the dialog box. the xhtml page works fine, but i need to show it in pop-up not separate xhtml page. I tried to do it  but it doesn't work. Here is the code i have written for dialog box when edit button is pressed. as you see i have used p:dialog for pop-up to appear. but when pressing edit button nothing happens and the dialog box does not appear.

studentsList.xhtml:

```
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Update</f:facet>
                <h:commandButton action="#{studentBean.editStudentRecord(student.id)}" value="Edit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="PF('dlg2').show();"/>
                </h:column>
        <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Delete</f:facet>
                <h:commandButton action="#{studentBean.deleteStudentRecord(student.id)}" value="Delete"
                                 class="btn btn-danger" onclick="if (confirm('Are u sure?') == false)
                             return false;"/>
            </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
            <p:dialog header="Update" widgetVar="dlg2" modal="true" height="200" width="600" dir="ltr">
                <h:form>
                <h:panelGrid columns="4" cellpadding="4">
                        <h:outputLabel for="name" style="font-weight:bold"/>
                        <p:inputText name="name" id="Nameid" type="text" value="#{student.name}"
                                     autocomplete="off"/>
                        <h:outputLabel for="password" style="font-weight:bold"/>
                        <p:inputText name="password" id="Passid" type="text" value="#{student.password}"
                                     autocomplete="off"/>
                        <h:outputLabel for="gender" style="font-weight:bold"/>
                        <p:selectOneRadio value="#{student.gender}"/>
                    <h:commandButton action="#{studentBean.updateStudentDetails(student)}" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="PF('dlg2').hide();"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </h:form>
            </p:dialog>
```

Can somebody tell me what is wrong with the dialog box and why it doesn't appear?

Comment: Please start by reducing the code in your question. 99% is not relevant. Just a 'hello' in one of of the pages you want to show is enough (having two is irrelevant too). And the original page does not need a full datatable either. Start by creating a [mcve] for the  'dialog' problem.

Comment: Where did I or the link talk about things being ambiguous? It is about making it **easier for us** to **help you**. We should not have to wade through irrelevant code to see what attempts are being made to have a dialog in one way or another.  And did you search? (excluded all frameworks that have complete functioning dialogs build in) https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=jsf+dialog+-primefaces+-bootsfaces+-angularfaces+-icefaces+-richfaces

Comment: No I cannot see the p:dialog (easily) since there is way to much irrelevant code and the two pages have no relation with the dialog whatsover. So [mcve]... please